# Livestream data from SQL to Power BI online service using PowerShell or other options

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powerbi

I have an assignment to setup a live Power BI online service tile using live data streaming from SQL table. The data in the table updates every few seconds. Here is what I got so far using PowerShell.

But it appears to be not refreshing the data set every few seconds. What am I missing?

```
DO
        {   
        $SqlServer = 'ServerName';
        $SqlDatabase = 'DBName';
        $sleepDuration = 3
        $SqlConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI' -f $SqlServer, $SqlDatabase;
        $SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable;";

        $SqlCommand = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
        $SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlQuery;
        $SqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $SqlConnectionString;
        $SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection;

        $SqlConnection.Open();
        $SqlDataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        ##you would find your own endpoint in the Power BI service
        $endpoint = "......My PowerBI Service Push URL.........."



        #Fetch data and write out to files
        while ($SqlDataReader.Read()) {
             $payload =  
            @{
            "Col1" =$SqlDataReader['Col1']
            "Col2" =$SqlDataReader['Col2']

                } 
            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
         # Sleep for a second
            Start-Sleep $sleepDuration
        }
        $SqlConnection.Close();
        $SqlConnection.Dispose();

        } While (1 -eq 1)
```

Comment: How many lines your query returns? I bet you just have too many rows. You need to extract all lines first and then make your http request

Comment: It makes no sense to me to send the contents of a table row by row and delay between each request. Are you sure you don't need to read and push the whole table every "few seconds"?

Comment: It returns one row at a time and yes that is part of the issue I was facing which I missed in my explanation. Also, how do I remove all the rows from the dataset first and then push new dataset. It is only few hundred total rows that is pushed every few seconds. Thanks guys!